# Where did this code come from?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was looking at [some question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192995/error-when-inserting-using-php) which had a edit pending. When I opened the edit I saw the following:

[image: insta-code]

By looking at this edit you see that before the edit there was no code at all. I don't think the editor made all that code up, so it looks like the pending edit box didn't show all the text in the original question.

Comment: @MrLister: The question was most likely not deleted at the time PeeHaa *started* posting his question here.

Comment: @MrLister no otherwise I would voted to undelete it :) My question was about not saying any code mebfore the edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was hidden in the left view because it was interpreted as HTML tags and filtered out; the bits between `<?php` and a `?>` at the bottom was stripped out.

You can use the diff mode icons at the left of the suggested edit to switch between different modes of display so you can see source code as wells as rendered posts:

[image: Show the markdown diffs side-by-side]

Comment: Have looked so many times at those icons wondering what they did. Never clicked it of course :)

Comment: @PeeHaa on Stack Overflow one should click **anything** - you won't believe how many hidden gems you can find this way! ;)

Comment: +1 for the freehand circle.

Answer (score 8):

Use the "Show Markdown Diffs Side By Side" option:

[image]

Comment: Apologies for reverting your edit; that was an accident as I was already in the process of posting my own screenshot. :-)

Comment: Is this free hand arrow? :)