# Edit that does not change anything

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

While reviewing edit suggestions, I sometimes come accross edits that claim to have changed something but there is no change apparent in the side-by-side comparison - see below for an example where the user says he has added syntax highlighting but the original code is already properly formatted. I checked the post and it was not showing any edits.

Assuming the editor did what he claims he did:

1. Is it due to the original poster having edited the post within the 5 minute period and after the edit suggestion has been made?
2. Shall I just reject the edit as too minor (although when the edit was made it was useful if 1. is true)?
3. Am I having hallucinations?

[image]

Comment: Semi-dupe of [Where did this code come from?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137594). It's answer applies here too.

Comment: Haha - the editor added `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` so I guess the answer to my 3 questions is that the answer to 3 is yes.

Comment: Ah yes I sometimes add the <!-- #language --> specifier if the syntax highlighting is incorrect (it's inherited from the most popular tag).

Comment: Ha! I'm not the only one :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mean [these revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11297405/revisions)?

If you take a look at the icons to the left of a revision, you can see that you can switch between representations of a change. Here I choose the 'show the markdown diffs':

[image: markdown diff showing that a language hint was added]

As you can see a syntax highlighting hint was added.

Comment: Yep - I did not know about that view. Very handy, thanks!